# Regular expression for a string containing one word but not another

Tags: regex, google-analytics, regex-negation

I'm setting up some goals in Google Analytics and could use a little regex help.

Lets say I have 4 URLs

```
http://www.anydotcom.com/test/search.cfm?metric=blah&selector=size&value=1
http://www.anydotcom.com/test/search.cfm?metric=blah2&selector=style&value=1
http://www.anydotcom.com/test/search.cfm?metric=blah3&selector=size&value=1
http://www.anydotcom.com/test/details.cfm?metric=blah&selector=size&value=1
```

I want to create an expression that will identify any URL that contains the string **selector=size** but does NOT contain **details.cfm**

I know that to find a string that does NOT contain another string I can use this expression:

```
(^((?!details.cfm).)*$)
```

But, I'm not sure how to add in the **selector=size** portion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 212, accepted):

This should do it:

```
^(?!.*details\.cfm).*selector=size.*$
```

`^.*selector=size.*$` should be clear enough. The first bit, `(?!.*details.cfm)` is a negative look-ahead: before matching the string it checks the string does not contain "details.cfm" (with any number of characters before it).

Comment: FYI, check out http://www.regexr.com/ for a nice way to test these expressions out.

Comment: Always forget about negative lookahead and it's so useful

Comment: `"http://www.anydotcom.com/test/search.cfm?metric=blah&selector=sized&value=1" =~ /^(?!.*details\.cfm).*selector=size.*$/ #=> 0` is incorrect. (Note the string contains `"...selector=sized..."`.) Also, why `.*$` at the end?

Answer (score 5):

```
^(?=.*selector=size)(?:(?!details\.cfm).)+$
```

If your regex engine supported posessive quantifiers (though I suspect Google Analytics does not), then I guess this will perform better for large input sets:

```
^[^?]*+(?<!details\.cfm).*?selector=size.*$
```

Comment: This assumes `selector=size` is always before `details.cfm`, which isn't the case in the last url.

Comment: Just to clear this up, it wasn't me. I can't see why someone would down-vote two answers here, they are both correct.

Comment: @Kobi: This should have been a look-ahead, corrected. Oh and by the way, I did not suspect it was your down-vote.

Answer (score 3):

regex could be (perl syntax):

```
`/^[(^(?!.*details\.cfm).*selector=size.*)|(selector=size.*^(?!.*details\.cfm).*)]$/`
```

Comment: This is a corrupted regex, the square brackets turn all the pattern sequences into combination of individual chars.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the regex in the accepted answer. It [also matches](https://regex101.com/r/Za6PIl/1) `abcselector=size`, `selector=sizeabc` etc.

A correct regex can be `^(?!.*\bdetails\.cfm\b).*\bselector=size\b.*$`

**Explanation of the regex at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fA3sJI/1):**

[image]

Comment: While you are not wrong, the regex as originally accepted met my need as your examples did not exist in the set of possible strings.

Comment: I think it would have better to have just left a comment on the selected answer saying that word boundaries are needed and give your example as to why. For one, it's a small thing, possibly an oversight. Moreover, anyone looking at the selected answer might not see your answer but they would see comments (as would @Kobi).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to avoid `--line-buffered` on a tail in a similar situation as the OP and Kobi's solution works great for me. In my case excluding lines with either "bot" or "spider" while including `' / '` (for my root document).

My original command:

```
tail -f mylogfile | grep --line-buffered -v 'bot\|spider' | grep ' / '
```

Now becomes (with `-P` perl switch):

```
tail -f mylogfile | grep -P '^(?!.*(bot|spider)).*\s\/\s.*$'
```