# An Xcode regex to find all classes which contain the text 'addObserver' but not 'removeObserver'?

Tags: regex, xcode

I have an Xcode project with 200 or so class files. All of these classes need to have addObserver/removeObserver balanced or there's a risk of crashes so I'm trying to find a way to show the problem files without having to manually scan each one.

Tried [this regex from another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209711/regex-to-find-files-containing-one-word-but-not-another)...

```
^(?!.[\s\S]*removeObserver).[\s\S]*addObserver.*$
```

...but it is returning classes that contain removeObserver.

Comment: What are the `.` dots for ? and I don't think a regular expression is the best solution here, why not just use string methods ?

Comment: I don't know what the dots are for. I just copied it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209711/regex-to-find-files-containing-one-word-but-not-another). Is there a way to use the search function to do compound searches without using regex?

Comment: I don't work with XCODE at all but there must be, anyway how big is the text your searching ?

Comment: It's an Xcode project with 200 or so class files.

Comment: I see, but how much each class file can contain, number of lines ?

Comment: I am not aware of a simple way to do this with Xcode's search facility (doesn't mean it doesn't exist, though) but have you considered to simply do two `grep`s from the command line? One to find a list of files with `addObserver` and one to find the files in that list that also contains `removeObserver`. Diff the two and you have your result. I am sure some real Unix hackers can come up with a smarter solution than that, too.