# Regex matching a string that includes a substring, but does not include a substring

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will match a string that contains a certain substring, but fails if it also contains different substring. I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word), but I'm not sure how to get it to work for my needs. In the interest of being specific as possible:

- Yes, it has to do this as part of the expression. I do not have access to the code that will be processing this.
- Yes, it needs to be one expression.
- It needs to work with PHP's regex flavor. I'm pretty sure it's being evaluated using preg

To give an idea of what I'm trying to do, I have a set of URLs I'm trying to filter. URLs that have "/somedir" in them I want to match, but I don't want it to match if it also has "somestring" in the URL.

So,

- www.somesite.com/somedir/index.html
- www.somesite.com/somedir/somotherdir/index.html
- www.somesite.com/somedir/somepage.html

would all match, but,

- www.somesite.com/somedir/somestring.html
- www.somesite.com/somedir/somestring/index.html

would both fail.

Comment: Why regex? A simple combination of `strpos` would work.

Comment: *"I'm pretty sure it's being evaluated using preg"* - you should know before asking because this differs (it's highly likely you're right, but well, find out ;)) - Also the code where the pattern is used is necessary as it can differ how a regular expression is used. Also you should outline what you've tried so far. E.g. mock your own code, provide the data to run through, output results, make the pattern a variable and try.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953039/regular-expression-for-a-string-containing-one-word-but-not-another

Comment: Thanks Crisp, that was exactly what I was looking for. It's moot now, but I'm working in a CMS and the bit that assigns modules to pages using the URL uses regular espressions. It's also the reason I don't know whether it used preg or not, that and I don't have time to go digging through a dozen files to figure it out. Again, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need a regex that will accept a certain pattern *only* if it is not surrounded by another pattern:

```
~
    (?(DEFINE)
        (?<ACCEPT> must-contain-pattern)
        (?<REFUSE> must-not-contain-pattern)
    )

    ^
        (?:(?!(?&REFUSE)).)*
            (?&ACCEPT)
        (?:(?!(?&REFUSE)).)*
    $
~ux
```

In the `DEFINE` block define the `ACCEPT` and `REFUSE` pattern according to your needs and this should work.

*Edit:* The pattern from above tailored for the case of yours by defining the two named sub-patterns:

```
~
    (?(DEFINE)
        (?<ACCEPT> \Q/somedir\E)
        (?<REFUSE> \Qsomestring\E)
    )

    ^
        (?:(?!(?&REFUSE)).)*
            (?&ACCEPT)
        (?:(?!(?&REFUSE)).)*
    $
~ux
```

Comment: That seems like a lot of work when the answer to the question Crisp linked to works. Besides that, I could not use multiple expressions.

Comment: lot of work? multiple expressions? Not at all because of the defines and this is a single expression, not multiple ones. You probably don't understand how it works, I give you an example by editing the answer. It's meant you can easily adopt it. Hopefully it's more clear then.