# javascript regex: string contains this, but not that

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to put together a regex pattern that matches a string that does contain the word "front" and does NOT contain the word "square". I have can accomplish this individually, but am having trouble putting them together.

front=YES

```
 ^((?=front).)*$
```

square=NO

```
 ^((?!square).)*$
```

However, how to I combine these into as single regex expression?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression for a string containing one word but not another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953039/regular-expression-for-a-string-containing-one-word-but-not-another)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use just a single negative lookahead for this:

```
/^(?!.*square).*front/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8miYav/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!.*square)` is negative lookahead to assert a failure if text `square` is present anywhere in input starting from the start position
- `.*front` will match `front` anywhere in input

Comment: Thanks for this! what if I wanted to test if it DID contain them both, in any order?

Comment: `if it DID contain them both, in any order` then use **`/^(?=.*square)(?=.*front)/`**

Comment: I understand your answer is order independent, the change is that now I WANT square. Can I just remove the exclamation point?.....SEE your edit....thanks!

Comment: I agree that is the correct answer.  But if you need "front" to be at the start of the string, you could use this:  `/^(?!.*square)front/`

Answer (score 0):

You could use lookahead assertions to express the logical and:

The final pattern would look like that:

```
^(?=.*?front)(?!.*square)
```