# Match path but not os.path

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to match the string `path` but not the string `os.path`. How do I go about that ? Tried [`(?!(os\.path))\bpath\b`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953039/regular-expression-for-a-string-containing-one-word-but-not-another) but I still get all `os.path`S

Comment: `(?<!os\.)\bpath\b` ?

Comment: @SebastianProske: seems to work - could you add an answer explaining why it works and how I can be sure it will mathc complex cases like `if path and not os.path.sep in path` for instance

Comment: From the given string, do you want to match all occurences of path that are not connected to os. or none at all?

Comment: I want all lines that contain the word path but not os.path only (or sys.path for that matter) so the line above should be a match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a look-behind based regex, like

```
(?<!os\.)\bpath\b
```

This basically matches the exact word `path` and ensures that it is not preceded by `os.` If you want to avoid similar constructs, like `sys.path` or `xx.path` you could use `(?<!\w\.)` as look-behind instead.

See the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/vkvKO2/1).

Comment: Thanks! why was mine failing so miserably ?

Comment: Your lookebhind was starting at the same position, as your match started, thus directly in front of `path` - and thus would always be correct. You might check this with `(?!(os\.path))..\.\bpath\b`...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip any `path` starting with `.` try

`(?<!\.)path`

This will skip `sys.path` or `os.path` but will match `path`.

e.g. if test strings is `if path and not os.path.sep in path`,

match will be:

if `path` and not os.path.sep in `path`

See demo at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5WM8A1/1)