# bash regex for word with some suffixes but not one specific

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I need (case-insensitive) all matches of several variations on a word--except one--including unknowns.

I want

```
accept
acceptance
acceptable
accepting
```

...but not "acception."  A coworker used it when he meant "exception."  A lot.

Since I can't anticipate the variations (or typos), I need to allow things like "acceptjunk" and "acceptMacarena"

I thought I could accomplish this with a negative lookahead, but this didn't give the results I needed

```
grep -iE '(?!acception)(accept[a-zA-Z]*)[[:space:]]' file
```

*The trick is* that I can accept (har) lines that *contain* "acception," provided that the other words match. For example **this line is okay** to match:

> The *acceptance* of the inevitable is the *acception*.

...otherwise by now I'd have piped grep through grep -v and been done with it:

```
grep -iE '(accept)[a-zA-Z]*[[:space:]]' | grep -vi 'acception'
```

I've found [some questions that are similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953039/regular-expression-for-a-string-containing-one-word-but-not-another) and many that are not quite so.  Using `a-zA-Z` is likely unnecessary in `grep -i` but I'm flailing.  I'm probably missing something small or basic...but I'm missing it nonetheless.  What is it?

Thanks for reading.

PS: I'm not married to grep--but I am operating in bash--so if there's a magic awk command that would do this I'm all ears (eyes).

PPS: forgot to mention that on https://regex101.com/ the above lookahead seemed to work, but it doesn't with my full grep command.

Comment: `missing something small or basic` grep doesn't support lookarounds... unless you have GNU grep with -P support...

Comment: Precisely.  I'm the guy in the movie who dies just before the hero makes it out alive.  Thanks Sundeep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use lookarounds, you need `GNU grep` with PCRE available

```
grep -iP '(?!acception)(accept[a-z]*)[[:space:]]'
```

With `awk`, this might work

```
awk '{ip=$0; sub(/acception/, ""); if(/accept[a-zA-Z]*[[:space:]]/) print ip}'
```

- `ip=$0` save input line
- `sub(/acception/, "")` remove unwanted words, can add other unwanted words with alternation
- `if(/accept[a-zA-Z]*[[:space:]]/) print ip` then print the line if it still contains words being searched

Comment: Perfect; thank you!  Changing E to P did it.  What's lame is just a couple weeks ago I used PCRE for something else.  It's short-term memory that wasn't quite committed yet to long-term knowledge.  Now it has.  :,/

Comment: Is there a reason I wouldn't want to replace my habit and permanently switch from `grep -E` to always using `grep -P` instead? Other than "*some systems won't support PCRE*" I mean?

Comment: one reason I can think of is `grep -E` would be faster for many cases.. while `grep -P` would generally be faster if back-references are involved... then other things like `grep -P` not being portable if GNU grep or PCRE lib not available..