# PyCharm: Find in Path: Skip import-statements

Tags: pycharm

If I use "Find in Path" (ctrl-shift-f) I see result in import statements, too:

[image: find-in-path--pycharm]

I am not interested in the `from ... import ...` lines.

How to remove them from "Find in Path"?

Comment: I guess the only solution is to use regex as there's no such built-in feature to ignore imports.

Comment: I created a feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-38839

Comment: If you want to search for where it's defined, use the "symbol" search, ie ctrl-alt-O (or cmd-opt-O).  From there you can search for usages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know of to do this in current editions is to use a regex:

```
(?<!import )logged_in_or_basicauth
```

This uses a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure that any matches that have the word `import` and a single space preceding `logged_in_or_basicauth` will be excluded from the results.

Note that quantifiers like `+` and `*` cannot be used in lookbehinds, so we can't make this regex handle multiple spaces between `import` and `logged_in_or_basicauth` aside from simply hardcoding more spaces after `import`.

I voted for your feature request on YouTrack, good idea opening it there.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that JetBrains IDE doesn't have such feature, the question turns to be "find a string which contains `target` but doesn't contain `import`". So see this: [Regular expression for a string containing one word but not another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953039/regular-expression-for-a-string-containing-one-word-but-not-another)

Use `^(?!.*import).*target.*$`.

Test cases:

```
from whatever import target;
import whatever from target;
target;
whatever target;
```

The problem is it will highlight other words.

Reg101 result:
[Reg101 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5liI.png)