# Is it possible to collapse these two grep queries into a single line command?

Tags: grep

I want to download the source of a web page and then check for the presence of one string, and the absence of another. I have working code below - is it possible to do this entire script as a one-line command?

```
PAGE_SOURCE=`curl https://example.com`

if ! echo "$PAGE_SOURCE" | grep -q "string that is bad"; then
    if echo "$PAGE_SOURCE" | grep -q "string that is good"; then
        exit 0
    fi
fi

exit 1
```

Comment: `if echo "$PAGE_SOURCE" | grep -Pq "^(?!.*string that is bad).*string that is good"; then`

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: No, I get the error message "unrecognized character after (? or (?-"

Comment: Sorry,  `grep -Pq '^(?!.*string that is bad).*string that is good'` should work, with single quotes. `!` is expanded in the double quoted strings.

Comment: Still does not work?

Comment: Looks like that works, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
if grep -Pq '^(?!.*string that is bad).*string that is good'; then
    exit 0
fi
```

The well-known PCRE pattern described in [Regular expression for a string containing one word but not another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953039) thread should be put inside a single-quoted string, or you will need to escape `!` char since it is used to expand history.

The short pattern description:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*string that is bad)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then `string that is bad` immediately to the right of the current location
- `.*string that is good` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then `string that is good`.